# SlideView starting below the navigationBar in PPRevealSlideViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

In My App, I am using PPRevealSlideViewController.

The problem is right side view is coming below the navigationBar as shown by red oval in the image. It is not starting from the extreme top. What will be the fix ?

Bothe left and right side viewControllers have navigationBar.

Code :

MainController main = [[MainController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainController" bundle:nil];

```
UINavigationController *navMainController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:main];

PPRevealSideViewController *revealSideViewController = [[PPRevealSideViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navMainController];

revealSideViewController.delegate = main;

[self.navController pushViewController:revealSideViewController animated:YES];

[main release];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to Impliment `PPRevealSlideViewController` Like this in to you project:-

```
LoginPageViewController *login = [[LoginPageViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginPageView" bundle:nil];  
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:login];
_revealSideViewController = [[PPRevealSideViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nav];
[self.window setRootViewController:_revealSideViewController];
```

i think into you code you adding two navigation Controller you need to add Just one Navigation controll while you add `PPRevealSideViewController` in to main pushviewcontroller in to `self.window`

**For Example you can achieve this**

at you `HomeViewcontroller push rightViewcontroller` you need to again rightViewcontrollre as a rootviewcontroller like Add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`:-

ObjAppDelegate=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; //create object of appdelegate

```
-(IBAction)ActionPushrightViewcontroller
{

         rightViewcontroller *login = [[rightViewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"rightViewcontroller" bundle:nil];  
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:login];
    _revealSideViewController = [[PPRevealSideViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nav];

          [ObjAppDelegate.window setRootViewController:_revealSideViewController];
             UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = _revealSideViewController.interfaceOrientation;
        NSString *subtypeDirection;
        if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
            subtypeDirection = kCATransitionFromTop;
        }
        else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
            subtypeDirection = kCATransitionFromBottom;
        }
        else {
            subtypeDirection = kCATransitionFromRight;
        }
        [ObjAppDelegate.window setRootViewController:_revealSideViewController];
        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setDuration:0.5];
        [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
        [animation setSubtype:subtypeDirection];
        [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

        [[ObjAppDelegate.window layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];


}
```

and if you want to back you Home view controller use this code:-

```
-(IBAction)ActionPopHomeviewcontroller
{

         Homeviewcontroller *Home = [[Homeviewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"Homeviewcontroller" bundle:nil];  
         UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:Home];

            UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = viewController.interfaceOrientation;
            NSString *subtypeDirection;
            if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
                subtypeDirection = kCATransitionFromTop;
            }
            else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
                subtypeDirection = kCATransitionFromBottom;
            }
            else {
                subtypeDirection = kCATransitionFromLeft;
            }

            [ObjAppDelegate.window setRootViewController:nav];


            CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
            [animation setDuration:0.5];
            [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
            [animation setSubtype:subtypeDirection];
            [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

            [[ObjAppDelegate.window layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];


}
```

Comment: @parilogic is that you adding two navigation controll one while you are trying to add PPRevealSideViewController and one is alread into rightviewcontroller

Comment: The mainviewcontroller also adding from appdelegate with navigation controller right?

Comment: as i atteched my code just create a Obj of appdelegate and get it's window class using object of delegate and add the mainview controller as a rootview controller again with CATransition push pop animation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38157/discussion-between-parilogic-and-nitin-gohel)